Java SQL Date Conversion Issue: Year Displays Incorrectly
I am experiencing an issue with retrieving dates from my SQL database using Java. The year returned is showing as 2024 in the database, but when I fetch it through my DAO, the year is converted to 2024 - 543 = 1481. I have confirmed that the SQL query returns the correct year (2024).
Here's a snippet of my DAO and Service code:
@Override
public List<Receipt> getAll() {
    ArrayList<Receipt> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM RECEIPT";
    Connection conn = DatabaseHelper.getConnect();
    try {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        
        while (rs.next()) {
            Receipt receipt = Receipt.fromResultSet(rs);
            list.add(receipt);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return list;
}

public static Receipt fromResultSet(ResultSet rs) {
    Receipt receipt = new Receipt();
    try {
        receipt.setId(rs.getInt("RECEIPT_ID"));
        receipt.setCreatedDate(rs.getTimestamp("R_DATETIME"));
        receipt.setTotal(rs.getDouble("R_TOTAL_PRICE"));
        receipt.setReceived(rs.getDouble("R_AMOUNT_RECEIVED"));
        receipt.setChange(rs.getDouble("R_CHANGE"));
        receipt.setTotalQuantity(rs.getInt("R_QTY"));
        receipt.setBranchId(rs.getInt("BRANCH_ID"));
        receipt.setUserId(rs.getInt("USER_ID"));
        receipt.setCustomerId(rs.getInt("CUSTOMER_ID"));
        receipt.setPaymentCode(rs.getInt("PAYMENT_CODE"));
        receipt.setPromotionID(rs.getInt("PROMOTION_ID"));
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Receipt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
    return receipt;
}

public List<Receipt> getReceipts() {
    ReceiptDao receiptDao = new ReceiptDao();
    return receiptDao.getAll();
}

Additional Information:

I have already tried changing the locale settings on my Windows system to see if that affects the output, but the issue persists.
The R_DATETIME field in the database is correctly stored as a TIMESTAMP.

Question: Why is the year being displayed incorrectly when it is retrieved in my Java application? How can I ensure that it displays as 2024 instead of being converted to 1481?

Value and Type Returned by rs.getTimestamp("R_DATETIME"):
The rs.getTimestamp("R_DATETIME") method returns a java.sql.Timestamp object. For example, if the R_DATETIME in the database is "2024-09-30 12:34:56", this is the value that should be retrieved.

Function of setCreatedDate():
The setCreatedDate(Timestamp createdDate) method in the Receipt class is used to set the createdDate property of the Receipt object. It stores the Timestamp object without any modification.



What is the type of the R_DATETIME column in the table?

What database engine?

I asked: 1) "which value is returned by rs.getTimestamp?", not which "should be retrieved" - I meant the actual value being returned! 2) "What is setCreatedDate() doing?" - I meant its code (as I also asked for a [mre]) - I sure was able to figure it is intended to set createdDate, given its name; but the question - I should be clearer - is how is it doing that? 3) "How you are seeing 1481?" again, regarding the request for a [mre] the question is more how - the code -  you "try to display or log the year" ...

1481 of the Thai Buddhist era? Not that I can explain why it turns up here, though.

I recommend that you use timestamp with time zone or equivalent in your database and OffsetDateTime in Java for a timstamp. The Java Timestamp class that you tried to use had bad design problems and has been outdated since JDBC 4.2. Please see the answer.

@Anonymous The equivalent of java.sql.Timestamp is java.time.LocalDateTime, as specified in JDBC 4.2 and higher. A SQL TIMESTAMP (a.k.a. TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE) has no time zone information. Support for SQL TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE was introduced in JDBC 4.2, and is only backed by a java.time.OffsetDateTime. This is one of the reasons the historic decision to base java.sql.Timestamp on java.util.Date was a bad one.

@MarkRotteveel True.

java.time
In March 2014, Java 8 introduced the modern, java.time date-time API which supplanted the error-prone legacy, java.util date-time API. Any new code should use the java.time API. If you are receiving an instance of java.util.Date, convert it tojava.time.Instant, using Date#toInstant and derive other date-time classes of java.time from it as per your requirement.
TIMESTAMP maps with LocalDateTime as shown in this table:



ANSI SQL
Java SE 8




DATE
LocalDate


TIME
LocalTime


TIMESTAMP
LocalDateTime


TIME WITH TIMEZONE
OffsetTime


TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE
OffsetDateTime



How to use LocalDateTime in JDBC?
Given below is a sample code to insert a LocalDateTime into columnfoo (which is of TIMESTAMP type):
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (columnfoo) VALUES (?)");
st.setObject(1, ldt);
st.executeUpdate();
st.close();

Given below is a sample code to retrieve a LocalDateTime from columnfoo:
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE <some condition>");
while (rs.next()) {
    // Assuming the column index of columnfoo is 1
    LocalDateTime ldt = rs.getObject(1, LocalDateTime.class));
    System.out.println(ldt);
}
rs.close();
st.close();

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from Trail: Date Time.
